# Replace groupByKey with reduceByKey to improve performance using complex data structures

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, rdd

We are creating JSON documents from CSV files, where the JSON is a complex object with nested objects and arrays. All of the columns are strings.

Currently, we accomplish this by:

1. Joining the CSVs (as DataFrames) into one DataFrame (joinedDf)
2. Doing a map to create objects within joinedDf
3. Doing a groupBy to create an array of the objects created in Step 2 (using collect_set in the agg section)
4. Doing another map to create more objects
5. Doing a final groupBy to create more arrays containing the objects from Step 4.

```
joinedDf = join_dfs(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
joinedDf1 = spark.createDataFrame(joinedDf.rdd.map(lambda x: createFirstSetOfObjects(x), schema=schema1).groupBy(set_of_columns).agg(collect_set(newObject1), collect_set(newObject2))
joinedDf2 = spark.createDataFrame(joinedDf1.rdd.map(lambda x: createSecondSetOfObjects(x), schema=schema2).groupBy(set_of_columns).agg(collect_set(newObject3), collect_set(newObject4), collect_set(newObject5))
```

As you can guess, the code is very slow, and we believe that we can optimize by:

- Replacing groupBy by reduceByKey
- Reduce the jumping from DataFrame to RDD and back

We are currently struggling with reduceByKey however, as all examples are around numerical operations (sum, avg, etc), whereas we are looking to collect columns into arrays and objects based on a set of columns.

Question:

1. Does anyone have a generic example of using reduceByKey to build complex data structures?
2. Does anyone have a generic example of using reduceByKey along with something close to collect_set to build complex data structures (we know that reduceByKey is a RDD function whereas collect_set is a DataFrame function)?